# Datepicker not changing value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, velocity

I am trying to change the value of a datepicker value, but everytime I select it on the calendar it does not change the value, but stays the same original value. How can I fix this?

Here is my code

```
$('#birthday').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "1901:2012"
});

#set ($formattedDate = $webFormatter.formatDateByPattern($webFormatter.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", $localBirthdate), "MM/dd/yyyy"))

<input type="text" id="birthday" name="birthday" value="$formattedDate" />
```

Comment: Just for information, did you add your script tag for your jquery ?

Comment: There is obviously something else going on here which is not included in your question.  The code works just fine independently.  http://jsfiddle.net/d4X9F/  Can you reproduce the issue in the fiddle?

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I had a wrong name for our server side validation. Instead of birthday it was birthdate. Sigh...Thanks guys for your help. I shall use JsFiddle more from now on.